# How to handle different types of data for a same row in a table?

Tags: database, schema

I'm working on a project and need a table that can handle different types of data depending of the type.

The type can be a link, an image, text or a set of colors. Only one of these 4 on each row.

Would it be better to create a parent table and then one table for each type? Or have one table with one column per type, leaving null the other three types thate "are not in use".

For example, my table is called "Idea"

**First solution:**

*ideas*

- Id
- Title

*idea_link*

- idea_id
- link

*idea_image*

- idea_id
- image_path

**Second Solution**

*ideas*

- Id
- Name
- Link (nullable)
- Image (nullable)
- Text (nullable)

Comment: it's not really related to data type but on relations. In the second solution each idea cannot have more than one link or image or text, in the first solution each idea can have several link. Check DB relations to understand the difference. Check for example: https://condor.depaul.edu/gandrus/240IT/accesspages/relationships.htm

Comment: Yes, in this case each idea can only have one link (or) one image (or) one "text". My question is, what is the best solution to handle that "or".

Comment: There's no really a "best" overall solution. Depends on what you want to achieve. If you have a one-to-one relation you must use second solution, if you have a one-to-many relation, you have to use first one.